# How can I proxy big contents with tornado on Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, reverse-proxy

I am trying to implement asynchronous http reverse proxy with tornado on Python3.

Handler class is as follows:

```
class RProxyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        backend_url = 'http://backend-host/content.html'   # temporary fixed

        req = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(
                                    url=backend_url)
        http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        http_client.fetch(req, self.backend_callback)

    def backend_callback(self, response):
        self.write(response.body)
        self.finish()
```

When content.html is small, this code works fine. But with large content.html, this code raises Exception:

```
ERROR:tornado.general:Reached maximum read buffer size
```

I found the way to handle large contents with pycurl. Though, it seems does not work with Python3.

In addition, I added streaming_callback option to HTTPRequest. But the callback won't be called when disabled chunked response by backend server.

How can I handle large contents?

Thanks.

Comment: This answer might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018684/tornado-streaming-http-response-as-asynchttpclient-receives-chunks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass `max_buffer_size` to the `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()`
 call to set the max buffer size.  for a 50MB buffer:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado import gen
from tornado.web import asynchronous


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    client = AsyncHTTPClient(max_buffer_size=1024*1024*150)

    @gen.coroutine
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        response = yield self.client.fetch("http://test.gorillaservers.com/100mb.bin", request_timeout=180)
        self.finish("%s\n" % len(response.body))

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

*Update:*  Now a full example program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though, response size is limited as ever. Can I relay contents as follows? (recv from backend) -> (store to buffer) -> (send to client) -> (clear buffer) -> (recv from backend) ...

Comment: I've updated the example to a full program, which will pull down a 100mb file.  This pretty much is the flow you described, unless you mean a streaming proxy.  You would have to write a full HTTP handler to implement a streaming proxy since you would need to hook onto the IOStream.

Comment: I tried your example program. When content size is bigger than max_buffer_size, this program raises "Reached maximum read buffer size" Exception. So, I guess that entire content is stored to buffer...

Comment: @bobunderson: Has there been any progress on this? I would like to use tornado as a proxy for large (as in multiple-GB) files

Comment: FYI If you're doing block-by-block downloads with the `streaming_callback` parameter of `fetch()` / `HTTPRequest()`, you can set `max_body_size` instead of `max_buffer_size` to increase the limit on the size of the entire download without increasing the limit on the size of each block.  See http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.simple_httpclient.SimpleAsyncHTTPClient for more info.

Comment: In the interest of it not getting missed, the default time limit for the entire download is 20 seconds, which isn't a lot of time if you're doing a large download on a slow connection, so you'll probably want to pass a `request_timeout` with a higher value as @koblas shows